Is there a way to write a sequence of text lines to a grid window?
Forgive my ignorance; I'm trying to get going with tkinter. I have gotten code to work to send text strings to various row/column entries using .grid. But if I want to just write a series of messages to one row/column, as one would use print statements to send many lines to the console, what would I do? I did this by using a row counter and incrementing it each time, which works, but is clunky.
Thanks!
This is my code to write a line:
msg = "Some formatted string"
Label(win, text = msg).grid(row = tk_row_num, column = 0, sticky = W)
tk_row_num = tk_row_num + 1


Example how to use Text with tags to change color: python - Changing the colour of text automatically inserted into tkinter widget - Stack Overflow

Try creating a text editor with tkinter.Text then insert your text into each row.
You can then paste or type text into the text editor.
The follow code will get you started.
import tkinter as tk

msg = "Some formatted string"

app = tk.Tk()

editor = tk.Text(app, undo = 1)
editor.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)
editor.insert('end', msg+'\n')

app.mainloop()


you could add line editor.insert('end', msg+'\n') to show how to use Text
